# Escape double quotes only if not already escaped

Tags: java, regex, string

Given a String as input, I want to escape all those double quotes that should have escaped but they did not. For instance, given `"<?xmlversion=\"1.0"encoding="UTF-8\"?>"` as input, the output should be `"<?xmlversion=\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"`. I was thinking of using Regex but was not fully sure how. I would appreciate if someone could help with that.

Comment: These questions always baffle me. What are you doing that is leading you *into* this problem? A proper XML parser won't ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could using a regex replacement here:

```java
String xml = "<?xmlversion=\\\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\\\"?>";
System.out.println(xml);
xml = xml.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\"", "\\\\\"");
System.out.println(xml);
```

This prints:

```xml
<?xmlversion=\"1.0"encoding="UTF-8\"?>
<?xmlversion=\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
```

The regex pattern used here is:

```
(?<!\\)"
```

This will target all double quotations which are *not* preceded by a backslash, and replace them with `\"`.  Note that we have to double escape the backslashes within Java's regex language.  Also literal double quote becomes `\"` in a Java string.